# How to change Tcp timestamp value?

Tags: tcp, timestamp

The question is straightforward and simple.

I want to know how to change the value of tcp timestamps manually in windows. I know how to disable them but i want to know the process of changing tcp timestamps value field to values that i want them to show. How can i achieve this.

Can we alter these timestamp values? I have read somehwere that it can be done and requires a detailed knowledge of how the kernel interprets system time and how this system time is reflected in the default OS generated fields in packet headers.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The TCP timestamps values are part of the protocol, they are not data fields.  They are used to protect against sequence space wrap-around.  If you could and did change them then there is the potential for breaking the protocol, however since Windows is not open-source I don't think you'll be able to anyway without creating a whole new IP stack.  You can get rid of them in Windows 7 by disabling the option but I don't know about Windows 10 (because I haven't checked)